# Comparing times between multiple dates in NSMutableArray NSDateComponent only returns the value of the first date

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsmutablearray

Basically I have an array that can contain multiple NSManagedObjects I'm trying to sort through these objects and for the ones that have a start date I want to compare the time between the start date and now or the start date and the end date if it is set. Lastly set a timer to refresh this information in a second.

The problem I am having is when comparing the times time only returns the value of the first object with a start date. If I add another value with start date the time sets to 0 and starts over when I want it to add them together.

If you need any more information let me know

I was using the for(object *obj in Array) before however it seemed to have more problems

```
int time = 0;
if([_ttimes count] != 0){

    for(int i=0; i < [_ttimes count]; ++i){
        TTime *tTime = [_ttimes objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"time%i", i);
        if(tTime.sDate){
            NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
            if(tTime.eDate){
                date = tTime.eDate;
            }
            NSDateComponents *component = [cal components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:tTime.sDate toDate:date options:0];
            int tmpTime = [component second];
            time = time + tmpTime;
        }
    }
    _ticketTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(TotalWorkTime) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Changed the method to this:

`-(void)TotalWorkTime{
    double time = 0;
    if([_ttimes count] != 0){
        for(TTime *tTime in _ttimes){
            NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
            if(tTime.eDate){
                date = tTime.eDate;
            }
            NSTimeInterval timerint = -[tTime.sDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date];
            time = time + timerint;
        }
        NSLog(@"Time:%f", time);
    }
}`

This seems to return a much more accurate time however thank you Zaph but this still down not solve the problem that time += timerint does not work right this number resets every time  I add a new object and it also only returns value for the last object added.

Comment: You are correct, fast enumeration can not be used on a user created class unless the fast enumeration support is added, that is usually easy to add.

Comment: OK I'll give it a try

Comment: while that is much cleaner then setting up a calendar it returns a negative value (not much of a problem ) but it still wont let me add the objects times

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `NSDateComponents` `components:NSSecondCalendarUnit` is that it only returns 0-59. (There are rare exceptions)

Further, since you are firing a timer every second there is a really good chance that the second (0-59) will be the same. To check this add logging with after `if(tTime.sDate)`:

```
NSLog(@"tTime.sDate: %@", tTime.sDate);
```

and see if the date is really the same of just the seconds are the same.

Instead of this:

```
NSDateComponents *component = [cal components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:tTime.sDate toDate:date options:0];
int tmpTime = [component second];
time = time + tmpTime;
```

Try this:

```
NSTimeInterval tmpTime = -[tTime.sDate timeIntervalSinceDate:date];
time += tmpTime;
```

Comment: the += seems to be acting the same as time = time + tmpTime but still not adding values of separate objects in the array

Comment: Yes, get a good book on the "C" programming language. Did you `NSLog(0` the actual dates, follow execution with the debugger?

Comment: Zaph thank you I have a couple C programming books 2 for C++ and I just bought the 3rd or 4th edition big nerd ranch but i figured it out had nothing to do with the information I had made the mistake of using addObject: rather then insertObject: atIndex: which was messing everything up thank you for your patients and is using a time interval method to get the time is that better then the other method or does it depend on the distance between dates. or is it just by preference